# How to find the length of an array class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
$param = k.chomp.split("\t")
```

How can I find the length of `$param` given that it is an array?
actually when I'm writing

```
puts $param.class
```

I got the o/p like Array.
Now how do I find the length of this array?

I tried `$param.length` but it's not working.

Comment: Are you sure you did `$param.length` not `$param.lenght`? What error message did you get?

Answer (score 38):

Ref [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) class

```
k = "This \t is \t just \t testing"
$param=k.chomp.split("\t")
array_length= $param.length   #or $param.size
puts "length of $param is : #{array_length}"
```

o/p

```
length of $param is : 4
```

Comment: thanks salil
$param.size is working but $param.length is not working

Answer (score 25):

Try using `.size` like this:

```
$param.size
```

Comment: Size is just an alias for length.